# Send push notifications for inbox messages

Tags: feature-request

How about using push notifications for notifying about inbox messages and maybe reputation history? It can be cumbersome to keep an eye on StackOverflow's tab in case somebody comments to one of my recent answers, or answers my recent questions.

It's really disturbing for me and I sometimes miss comments for some long while

[image: Push notification]

It's simple, neat, and optional.

Comment: Also, check out http://stackapps.com/search?q=desktop+notifications and [StackApplet — Bringing Stack Exchange Notifications to Your Desktop \[Large scale rewrite in progress\]](http://stackapps.com/q/83)